# How to load multiple images in ImageViews (parse.com)

Tags: android, parse-platform

I'm saving 5 images to my class in parse.com. I'm able to download one image based on objectid in a imageView. I need to download all 5 images to my 5 ImageViews. How can I do this. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("Footer");
            // Locate the objectId from the class
    query.getInBackground("tNp607WyQD", new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
                public void done(ParseObject object,ParseException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    // Locate the column named "ImageName" and set
                    // the string
                    ParseFile fileObject = (ParseFile) object.get("imageFile");
                    fileObject.getDataInBackground(new GetDataCallback() {
                                public void done(byte[] data,ParseException e) {
                                    if (e == null) {
                                        Log.d("test","We've got data in data.");
                                        // Decode the Byte[] into
                                        // Bitmap
                                        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0,data.length);
                                        // Get the ImageView from main.xml
                                        //ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ad1);
                                        ImageView ad1=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ad1);
                                        // Set the Bitmap into the
                                        // ImageView
                                        ad1.setImageBitmap(bmp);
                                        // Close progress dialog
                                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                                    } else {
                                        Log.d("test",
                                                "There was a problem downloading the data.");
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                }
            });
}}
```

Comment: if random ,you can put all your ImageView to a list or stack first,then set the image to view if loaded.

Comment: @venciallee Can u pls let me know how to put all ImageView to a list ??

Comment: do you have the list of all the objectids you want to query? How do you intend to query to get the desired parseobjects?

Comment: @droidx I want to fetch all images on basis of createdAt timestamp. and then displaying each image in separate imageview.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm able to resolve this with help of imageloader class:

```
public class Login extends Activity {
public ImageLoader imgl;
EditText fullname, mobilenumber, occupation;
 Button save;
 ImageView ad1,ad2,ad3,ad4,ad5,ad6;  
 List<ParseObject> ob;

 private ImageView[] imgs = new ImageView[5];
 ProgressDialog progressDialog;
 int i=0;
 HorizontalScrollView horizontalScrollView1;        

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.userdata);
     imgl=new ImageLoader(getApplicationContext());
     fullname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.fullname) ;
     mobilenumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.mobile) ;
    occupation = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.occupation) ;
     save=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSave);      
    horizontalScrollView1=(HorizontalScrollView) findViewById(R.id.horizontalScrollView1);
    ad1=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ad1);
    ad2=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ad2);
    ad3=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ad3);
    ad4=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ad4);
    ad5=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ad5);
    ad6=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ad6);
     imgs[0] = ad2; 
     imgs[1] = ad3; 
     imgs[2] = ad4; 
     imgs[3] = ad5; 
     imgs[4] = ad6;

     progressDialog= ProgressDialog.show(Login.this, "","Downloading Image...", true);
                // Locate the class table named "Footer" in Parse.com
     ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>(
             "Footer");
     query.orderByDescending("updatedAt");
     try {
        ob = query.find();
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
     for (ParseObject country : ob) {
         ParseFile image = (ParseFile) country.get("imageFile");
         imgl.DisplayImage(image.getUrl(), imgs[i]);
        i=i+1;
         System.out.println("the urls are"+image.getUrl());
     progressDialog.dismiss();
     }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this? (Maybe it's a very crude way)

Since you have 5 (defined) imageviews, create an array of imageviews.

```
private ImageView iv1, iv2, iv3, iv4, iv5;
private ImageView[] imgs;
```

In onCreate(),

```
imgs = new ImageView[5];
iv1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv1);
iv2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv2);
iv3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv3);
```

and so on

then set the imageview array, like this,

```
imgs[0] = iv1;
imgs[1] = iv2;
imgs[2] = iv3;
```

//so on

In your ParseQuery, assuming you get the required list of ParseObjects (5, I believe),
in done method of GetCallBack,

```
public void done(List<ParseObject> objects,ParseException e) {
for(int i =0 ; i < objects.size(); i++){

           ParseObject object = objects.get(i);
           ParseFile fileObject = (ParseFile) object.get("imageFile");
           fileObject.getDataInBackground(new GetDataCallback() {
                                public void done(byte[] data,ParseException e) {
                                    if (e == null) {

                                        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0,data.length);
                                        imgs[i].setImageBitmap(bmp);

                                    } else {
                                        Log.d("test",
                                                "There was a problem downloading the data.");
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                }
progressDialog.dismiss();
}
```

In the ParseQuery, to get images in ascending order of createdAt, use

```
query.orderByAscending("createdAt");
```

Just incase if you face any problem with the variable 'i' in the ParseQuery, (particularly, you may not be allowed to use i inside done() and will ask you to declare it as final), let me know!

Comment: I also need to add the line after this ?   `query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {`

Comment: which? the query one? FOr query one, you need to add it after initializing the ParseQUery ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("Footer"); query.orderByAscending("createdAt");

Comment: ahh! yeah could solve it by making it global but not sure if its the best way! :)

Comment: Did you get the imageviews working? let me know if you need help with the ParseQuery.

Comment: oops! I forgot to initialize the imageview array...check the edited ans...imgs = new ImageView[5];

Comment: now it says ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException at `imgs[i].setImageBitmap(bmp);`

Comment: Did you reach to some solution?

Comment: Can u look this, I'm able to pull one image .. I think there must be sm prblm with loop

Comment: Yes, but with the help of ImageLoader .. Pasted the answer above !! :)

Comment: okay..that's great! I liked the idea of using the getUrl() method of ParseFile. You could also explore Picasso for handling loading/caching of images. Anyways, glad it worked out! Please do vote up my answer if it helped you to reach your solution :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to refactor your code in such a way that you can create a customised instance of your download task.

For example, create a FooterQuery class which wraps the ParseQuery. When you construct the object, you pass in the parseId and the resource id of the ImageView that it should be loaded into.

If the ImageView is controlled by an AdapterView (list a List or Grid view), it is going to be more complex.